# Alerts in bootstrap & pug

Tags: css, node.js, bootstrap-4, pug

I would like to know whether i have understood the workings of connect-flash/bootstrap/sessions. I do see the flash messages appear as expected. My question is to do with the colors related to the 'success' and 'danger'. While the messages appear as expected i am not seeing the associated colors,

Below are bits of package.json,

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.15",
    "pug": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  }
}
```

In my app.js,

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');

// express session middleware

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

// express messages middleware

app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
    next();
});

app.use(flash());

// my routes

let quotes = require('./routes/quotes');
let subscribers = require('./routes/subscribers');
app.use('/quotes', quotes);
app.use('/subscribers', subscribers);

// In my subscribers route,
router.post('/subscribe', function (req, res) 
{
// logic to save to my database here

req.flash('success', 'Subscription confirmed.');
res.redirect('back');
});
```

In my services.pug file i have,

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
// other code in here
.container
                h1 Subscribe to our newsletter
                //- include subscribe.pug
                form(method='POST', action= '/subscribe')
                    input(name = 'email',type='email', placeholder='Enter email')
                    button.button1(type='submit') Subscribe
                    != messages('message',locals)

// at the bottom

script(src='/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    script(src='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
```

In my message.pug i have,

```
.messages 
    each type in Object.keys(messages)
        each message in messages[type]
            div(class = "alert alert-"+ type) #{message}
```

Like i mentioned above the messages appear as expected. But i do not see the green color associated with success and the red for danger as i have seen in a tutorial i followed. I just see the message blended with the background color of the page. I would like to know what i am missing.

**UPDATE**

On checking the console on chrome i found the attached error messages. I have included the directory structure of the project as well. The bootstrap.css and jquery.js are not being found by the app.

This is where i set my public folder in app.js,

```
// set public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

[image: project directory structure] [image: Error on console]

The node_modules folder is available as well.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: I believe it has something to do with my custom css overriding bootstrap. When I inspect on chrome I am seeing ‘inherited from section#newsletter’ and the corresponding code from my custom css. What gets me confused though is that I still do not see the color after disabling my custom css.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to serve `bootstrap` and `jquery` *dist* folders beside the public one:

```
// set public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// serve bootstrap and jquery
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'bootstrap', 'dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'jquery', 'dist')));
```

and use them ( make sure styles are in `head` tag ):

```
link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/bootstrap.css')
link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
```

and:

```
script(src='jquery.js')
script(src='/js/bootstrap.js')
```

of course in production you should use minified versions ( i.e: `bootstrap.min.js` ) or simply a **CDN** ( or both: when CDN is not available fall back to local ones )

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I can confirm the styles were already in the head tag. So I did implement the changes and the outcome still remains the same i.e. I see errors when I inspect on chrome.

Comment: I am getting 404 on jquery.js. For the bootstrap.css I am getting ‘Refused to apply style from :3000/css/bootstrap.css’ because it’s MIME type ....’. Basically the same errors as in the images I attached with the question but with different paths due to the changes.